# c# using return and timer

Tags: c#, winforms

I am quite new to C# and I am trying to practice. But with this method, time and date informations only works for once i think because of return. What should I do in such a situation?

```
    private void startBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {           
            System.Timers.Timer timer = new System.Timers.Timer();
            timer.Interval = 1000;
            timer.Elapsed += timer_Elapsed;
            timer.Start();
    }

 public string google_date()
    {
        var myHttpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://google.com");
        var response = myHttpWebRequest.GetResponse();
        string todaysDates = response.Headers["date"];
        return DateTime.ParseExact(todaysDates, "ddd, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss 'GMT'", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.DateTimeFormat, DateTimeStyles.AssumeUniversal).ToString();            
    }



    void timer_Elapsed(object sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        //google_date();
        Console.WriteLine("Google Date Info: " + google_date().ToString());

    }
```

Comment: Side note: you're calling `google_date` twice each time the timer ticks. You should either remove the first `google_date();` or do something like `string value = google_date();` and then in the second line, `+ value` instead of `+ google_date()`.

Comment: But i want to get time and date information every 1 sec?

Comment: Why create the `Timer` in the `Click` event handler? Why not create it separately and then just call `Start` in the `Click` event handler? The way you have it, if the user clicks that `Button` multiple times, you'll create multiple `Timers`.

Comment: Why have you declared that method as returning a `string` and then you return a `DateTime`?

Comment: @jmcilhinney There's a `.ToString()` at the end.

Comment: @41686d6564standsw.Palestine, oops! Should have scrolled. I assumed that it was a `DateTime` because the `Elapsed` event handler is calling `ToString` on the result and I assumed that no one would call `ToString` on a `String`.

Comment: Your code is correct. Every second it will log a new datetime to console. Is that not what you want?

Comment: This is what i want but nope it is not log a new line.

Comment: @JozefStone perhaps the issue elsewhere, I copied and pasted your code and it works as you say you want it to.

Comment: It just log only two times for me.

Answer (score 3):

You need to modify your code a bit.

1. Don't call `google_date()` twice in an interval, instead store the date value in a variable that you can access again.
2. You need to replace `WebRequest.Create` function because it is obsolete. use `HttpClient` instead.
3. Return date values relative to `UTC`.
4. If you want to show the value in a UI control, you can avoid the `cross-thread operation not valid` exception by using the example below.

**Example:**

```csharp
bool isTimerActive = false;

private void startBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Only run timer one
    if (isTimerActive == false)
    {
        System.Timers.Timer timer = new System.Timers.Timer();
        timer.Interval = 1000;
        timer.Elapsed += timer_Elapsed;
        timer.Start();
        isTimerActive = true;
    }
}

void timer_Elapsed(object sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
    var date = google_date().Value.ToString("ddd, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss 'GMT'");
    if (textBox1.InvokeRequired)
    {
        textBox1.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate
        {
            textBox1.Text += date + Environment.NewLine;
        }));
    }
}

public static DateTimeOffset? google_date()
{
    using (var client = new HttpClient())
    {
        try
        {
            var result = client.GetAsync("https://google.com",
                  HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead).Result;
            return result.Headers.Date;
        }
        catch
        {
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

**Output:**
[image: Winforms show current time]

Comment: @JozefStone I have updated my answer. It includes a better way to get current time because `WebRequest.Create` is obsolete. The GMT date is now valid than previous one.

Comment: It just log only two times for me.

Comment: @JozefStone Could you try with a different log maybe use a UI control just to check if it still logs only two times. You can also use `Debug.WriteLine(date);`. Let me know

Comment: @JozefStone Can you add `timer.AutoReset = false;` in `startBtn_Click` to trigger once and then at the beggining of `timer_Elapsed` add `timer.Start();` to restart timer again. Maybe it could help. Additionally, upgrade your .NET framework if possible.

Comment: Im on 4.8, also i just changed google_date method to static class its working now but i need to make parse exact.   static class google_date
        {
            public static string todaysDates = HttpWebRequest.Create("http://google.com").GetResponse().Headers["date"];
        }

Comment: With this,  public static string todaysDates = HttpWebRequest.Create("http://google.com").GetResponse().Headers["date"];
            public static string date2 = DateTime.ParseExact(todaysDates, "ddd, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss 'GMT'", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.DateTimeFormat, DateTimeStyles.AssumeUniversal).ToString(); .. I think its okey but now i need to optimise that what u said in there: ". It includes a better way to get current time because WebRequest.Create is obsolete. The GMT date is now valid than previous one."

Comment: @JozefStone Glad its working now. Yes `HttpWebRequest.Create` is obsolete in newer version of .Net, there is no need to use it, instead use `HttpClient`. Also If you want GMT date values I recommend you use the latest function `google_date` function which uses `DateTimeOffset` and represents a date and time value relative to universal time.

Comment: @JozefStone If my answer helped your issue, please do accept my answer.

Comment: you have been very helpful thank you